# Vertical-align not working inside of td

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align my `div` (which is inside of a `td`) to be at the top, but `vertical-align: top` is not working. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hreDw/1/ (I want that yellow `b` to be at the top)

How can I do this? Also, amount of `a's` inside of the second td is dynamic - so the height of the table is also dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The `vertical-align` CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an inline or table-cell box.

[Read more about `vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Therefore, you have to apply the `vertical-align` property to the `td` element:

```
.first {
    background-color:black;
    min-height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.first div {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.second {
    background-color:green;
    min-height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `vertical-align` has to be on the `td` and not the `div`.

Right now you are simply applying the vertical alignment to the `div` itself, but instead you want everything in the `TD` to be vertically aligned:

```
.first {
    background-color:black;
    min-height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```